# Pytest use django_db with rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I am trying to get a simple test to work against the real `django_db` not the test database using the `django rest framework`.

Basic test setup:

```
import pytest
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_airport_list_real():
    client = APIClient()
    response = client.get(reverse('query_flight:airports-list'))
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert len(response.json()) > 0
```

Running this test I get:

```
___________________________ test_airport_list_real ____________________________

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_airport_list_real():
        client = APIClient()
        response = client.get(reverse('query_flight:airports-list'))
        assert response.status_code == 200
>       assert len(response.json()) > 0
E       assert 0 > 0
E        +  where 0 = len([])
E        +    where [] = functools.partial(<bound method Client._parse_json of <rest_framework.test.APIClient object at 0x000001A0AB793908>>, <Response status_code=200, "application/json">)()
E        +      where functools.partial(<bound method Client._parse_json of <rest_framework.test.APIClient object at 0x000001A0AB793908>>, <Response status_code=200, "application/json">) = <Response status_code=200, "application/json">.json

query_flight\tests\query_flight\test_api.py:60: AssertionError
```

When just running in the shell using `pipenv run python manage.py shell` I get the expected results:
    In [1]: from django.urls import reverse

```
In [2]: from rest_framework.test import APIClient

In [3]: client = APIClient()

In [4]: response = client.get(reverse('query_flight:airports-list'))

In [5]: len(response.json())
Out[5]: 100
```

Using the following packages:

```
pytest-django==3.2.1
pytest [required: >=2.9, installed: 3.5.1]
djangorestframework==3.8.2
django [required: >=1.8, installed: 2.0.5]
```

Is there anyway to get `pytest` to access the real database in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `django_db` marker is only responsible to provide a connection to the test database for the marked test. The django settings passed to `pytest-django` are solely responsible for the selection of database used in the test run.

You can override the database usage in `pytest-django` by defining the `django_db_setup` fixture. Create a `conftest.py` file in the project root if you don't have it yet and override the db configuration:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup():
    settings.DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'path/to/dbfile.sqlite3',
    }
```

However, you shouldn't use the real database in tests. Make a dump of your current db to get a snapshot of test data (`python manage.py dumpdata > testdata.json`) and load it into an empty test database to populate it before the test run:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest
from django.core.management import call_command

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        call_command('loaddata', 'testdata.json')
```

Now, you can't possibly corrupt your real db when running tests; any future changes in real db will not cause the tests to fail (for example, when some data was deleted) and you always have a deterministic state on each test run. If you need some additional test data, add it in JSON format to `testdata.json` and your tests are good to go.

Source: [Examples in `pytest-django` docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#examples).

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple options. Using Django's `TestClient` or DRF's `APIClient` will use the test database and local version of your app by default. To connect to your live API, you could use a library like [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to perform HTTP requests, then use those responses in your tests:

```
import requests

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_airport_list_real():
    response = requests.get('https://yourliveapi.biz')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert len(response.json()) > 0
```

Just be extra careful to perform exclusively read-only tests on that live database.

Comment: I thought `pytest-django` was supposed to be able to access the real database through the `@pytest.mark.django_db` flag.

Comment: @DavidFolkner That decorator makes your Django test database available in the function it decorates. It [works the same way](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#enabling-database-access-in-tests) as Django's `TestCase` class, but the syntax is more succinct.

Comment: that makes a lot more sense.  I was mis-using it then.